# postgresql: pass variable to sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to pass a variable to a select statement using PostgreSQL. The overall goal is to use this logic in a stored procedure where the variable `deadline_interval` would be an input parameter. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
  date_deadline date;
  deadline_interval varchar := '6 month';
BEGIN
  date_deadline := (SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL deadline_interval);
  RAISE NOTICE 'here: %', date_deadline;
END;
$$
```

Unfortunately the variable `deadline_interval` is undefined in the select statement. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a cast instead of the prefix.

```
...
date_deadline := (SELECT CURRENT_DATE - deadline_interval::interval);
...
```

Or, even better, use `interval` as type for `deadline_interval` from the beginning.

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
  date_deadline date;
  deadline_interval interval := INTERVAL '6 month';
BEGIN
  date_deadline := (SELECT CURRENT_DATE - deadline_interval);
  RAISE NOTICE 'here: %', date_deadline;
END;
$$
```